# can i add multiple value in field ? (please see an image)

Tags: forms, drupal, cck, multivalue

I need to do the stock management website with 2 Content type Supplier and Product. First I add contents in Supplier content type. Then I add node reference field in Product content type and call it supplier and make it multiple value. it's looks good, i can select suppliers and save it. but in my concept i need to check which supplier sale this product and how price. so i need to add suppliers and price in the same form like my image.

[image]

the propose of this form, user can check how price of each supplier for this product and they can choose the lowest price for purchase in the next process.

Guys, did you have the idea that i can do like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your image attached, I'd assume you have Druapl 7. 
You can do this by installing [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. To get the table-input, install [Field Collection Table](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table).

Core Fields can have multiple instances of the same field. But you can't group them and make the whole group a multi-instance group.

Drupal 6 required CCK module to have fields, and there was a MultiGroup module (CCK 3branch which never had a stable release) that does the similar for Drupal 6.

Although OP will not need this, dear Googler if you are looking for a simple table with text fields, try [TableField](http://drupal.org/project/tablefield) module